# Sum of products proof

Tags: summation, products

Let
$$
l_i(x)=\prod_{j=0,\ i\neq j}^n \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}
$$
where $x_0,...x_n\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall_{i,j}\ i\neq j \implies x_i\neq x_j$

Show that:
$$
\forall_{x\in \mathbb {R}}\ \sum_{i=0}^n l_i(x)=1
$$

I know how to do it when $x\in\{x_0,...,x_n\}$, but I don't know how to prove it for any $x$

Comment: __Hint:__ View it as a degree $\leq n$ polynomial. You've found that it agrees on $n+1$ values, so ....

Comment: @CalvinLin ah, that was so obvious, thank you!